# Unable to save data in "has_many through" relation from API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-6

I am using Ruby on Rails API with Postgresql I have two models `subject` and `teacher`, which has a relation "many to many", so using intermediate table `subject_teacher`. I want to create a map where which teacher is teaching which subject. All I want to store  the ID's of teacher and subject in front of each other so that I can fetch them using `JOIN` later. (or suggest any other alternative).

Using Ruby on Rails 6.1

### MIGRATIONS

**Teacher**

```rb
class CreateApiV1Teacher < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    create_table :api_v1_teacher do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

**Subject**

```rb
class CreateApiV1Subject < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    create_table :api_v1_subject do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

**Subject Teacher**

```rb
class CreateApiV1SubjectTeacher < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    create_table :api_v1_subject_teacher do |t|
      t.belongs_to :teacher
      t.belongs_to :subject
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

### MODEL

**Teacher**

```rb
class Api::V1::Teacher < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :subject_teacher
    has_many :subject, :through => :subject_teacher
end
```

**Subject**

```rb
class Api::V1::Subject < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :subject_teacher
    has_many :teacher, :through => :subject_teacher
end
```

**SubjectTeacher**

```rb
class Api::V1::SubjectTeacher < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :teacher
    belongs_to :subject
end
```

### CONTROLLER (Post Method)

I want to take array from front-end and save entries in DB (or any other alternative to make things faster ?)

```rb
class V1::SubjectTeacherController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_api_v1_subject_teacher, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]

  def create
    @api_v1_subject = Api::V1::SubjectTeacher.new(api_v1_my_subject_teacher)

    if @api_v1_subject.save
      render json: @api_v1_subject, status: :created, location: @api_v1_subject
    else
      render json: @api_v1_subject.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

   def api_v1_my_subject_teacher
     params.require(:my_ids).permit([:teacher_id, :subject_id])
   end
end
```

**JSON**

```json
{
    "my_ids": [
        {
            "teacher_id": 1,
            "subject_id": 2
        },
        {
            "teacher_id": 1,
            "subject_id": 3
        }
    ]
}
```

I am new to Ruby on Rails and backend any other alternative method or new way will be a great help.

Thank you

Comment: You don't normally version your models. Your models are an internal implementation detail which are not tied to a specific version of your API.

Comment: Actually I ran command ‘rails generate scaffold /api/v1/teachers’ so it did everything on its own

Comment: My point still stands - the scaffold generators work ok for rapid prototyping in classical apps but not so much for a versioned API.

Comment: @max okay will keep in mind :) btw any idea with the issue?

Comment: Yes. This code will only actually work if you wanted to create a single record. Creating multiple records at once is far more complex and you need to look in things like [nested attributes](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html).  No offensive but you really want to figure out the basics before you go there.

Comment: @max any good place to learn basics? If you can recommend any book or video or something. It would be helpful.

Comment: Unfortunately not that are relevant today. The Rails guides have some good content and API design is an entire subject in itself.

Comment: @max okay will check Thank you.